# After i update background color of selected item in listview, if i scroll background changes to random item and it selects multiple items too, why?

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

> My code :

```
ArrayList<Integer> selectedItemIds = new ArrayList<>();
boolean isItemSelected = false;

    main_listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
         @Override
         public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

             Object object = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

             if(object instanceof Listview_Item_Details)
             {
                 TextView itemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_itemName);
                 TextView itemDetails = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.listview_itemDetails);


                 if(!selectedItemIds.isEmpty())
                 {
                     for(int i = 0; i < selectedItemIds.size();i++)
                     {
                         if(selectedItemIds.get(i) == position)
                         {
                             isItemSelected = true;
                             if(selectedItemIds.size() == 1)
                             {
                                 selectedItemIds.clear();
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                 selectedItemIds.remove(i);
                             }
                         }
                     }

                     if(isItemSelected)
                     {
                         view.findViewById(R.id.custom_listview_item).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_item_background);
                         itemName.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBlack));
                         itemDetails.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGray_Dark));
                         isItemSelected = false;
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         selectedItemIds.add(position);
                         view.findViewById(R.id.custom_listview_item).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_selected_item_background);
                         itemName.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
                         itemDetails.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

                     }
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     selectedItemIds.add(position);
                     view.findViewById(R.id.custom_listview_item).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_selected_item_background);
                     itemName.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
                     itemDetails.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
                 }
             }

             return true;
         }
     });
```

> **NOTE : "custom_listview_item" is RelativeLayout of custom layout for item, in which both textviews are.**
>
> Now everythings works but like i said in question, if i DONT scroll the listview and selected/unselect multiple items, it works but i scroll it randomly changes background of multiple items and even changes background of selected items too.
>
> **What is the problem here?**

Comment: Do not change item view's properties inside `ItemClick` . Do it inside `getView()` of adapter . In `ItemClick` make chnages to dataset only and notify the adapter .

Comment: Recyclerview reuses all his cells for performance, you must explicity set your original background color to cells that have not been clicked.

Comment: @ADM you mean create method that overrides getView of adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Recyclerview` instead of `Listview` to handle this kind of situations and customizing the view items.